# CMake: Attempted to add link library to target which is not built in this directory

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, cmake

I'm having a an issue compiling some unit tests in my cmake project. The idea is to add these boost unit tests as executables, so that I can then run them. Anyway I'm getting this error that I don't quit understand, which is saying that I cannot link my cpp unit tests which must be linked to test the library I built. The two unit tests I'm trying to link and add as executables are, DownloadTickers.cpp and GetTickersForLetter.cpp.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
> Algo
  > build (this is where I do: cmake .. which gives me errors)
  -CMakeLists.txt (top level cmake)
  -algo.h.ini
  -run.cpp
  > NetworkModule
   > CrawlTickers
    -CMakeLists.txt
    -CrawlTickers.cpp
    -CrawlTickers.hpp
    > tests
     -CMakeLists.txt
     -DownloadTickers.cpp
     -GetTickersForLetter.cpp
```

The CMakeLists.txt for Algo is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (Algo)

set (Algo_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
set (Algo_VERSION_MINOR 1)
set (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++-4.8)
set (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

add_definitions(
  -std=c++11
)

configure_file(
  "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/algo.h.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/algo.h"
)

include_directories("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")

add_subdirectory(NetworkModule/CrawlTickers)

add_executable(Run run.cpp)
```

The CMakeLists.txt for CrawlTickers is:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

add_library(CrawlTickers SHARED CrawlTickers.cpp)

add_subdirectory(tests)

target_link_libraries(
  CrawlTickers
  cpprest
)

target_link_libraries(
  DownloadTickers
  CrawlTickers
  ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
)

target_link_libraries(
  GetTickersForLetter
  CrawlTickers
  ${Boost_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY}
  ${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
)
```

The CMakeLists.txt for tests is:

```
add_executable( DownloadTickers DownloadTickers.cpp )

add_executable( GetTickersForLetter GetTickersForLetter.cpp )
```

My thinking is that cmake would naturally register DownloadTickers and GetTickersForLetter as executables in the CrawlTickers CMakeLists.txt and then know how to link it to the target, but I have no idea why I'm getting this error. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Put the `target_link_libraries` calls in the same CMakeLists.txt as the `add_executable`

Comment: @Peter - why not put this as an 'answer' so I can up-vote it? Solution worked for me.

Comment: FWIW: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/2370

Answer (score 11):

The `target_link_libraries` directive needs to be part of the same `CMakeLists.txt` as the `add_executable` directive.  This also applies to libraries.  Think of each directory and associated `CMakeLists.txt` as a subproject.

As pointed out in the comments, CMake 3.13 now allows the requested behavior.

Comment: I got this issue but in a function defined in a custom .cmake-script... Any workaround? Trying to append coverage-flags for a target passed in as argument...

Comment: @helmesjo That sounds like a different question.  Ask a new one?

Comment: Same error message but yes, it might be desirable to have it as a separate question. Thanks anyways!

Comment: This [policy](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0079.html#policy:CMP0079) is now disabled by default in CMake 3.13 and greater.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant policy (CMP0079) was already mentioned in the comments, but I suppose the actual solution need to be clearly stated. With CMake 3.13 and above you need to add the following line to your top-level CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(POLICY CMP0079 )
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0079 NEW)
endif()
```

This allows the use of `target_link_libraries()` with targets defined in other directories.

You could also increase the CMake minimum version instead:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.13)
```

But that will change a whole bunch of policies (essentially, everything from CPM0024 to CMP0081) to `NEW` which may not be desirable for existing projects.

Comment: are you sure you need to explcitly set it if you have CMake 3.13+? I thought `NEW` is the default for policies once they are defined?

Comment: @starball, `NEW` is the default only if your project claims to be compatible with the new version of CMake using `cmake_minimum_required`. Otherwise `OLD` is the default until the policy is eventually removed from CMake, at which point only `NEW` behavior is available.