# How to create a template for creating a test executable using catch2 with qt and trompeloeil?

Tags: qt, cmake, catch2, trompeloeil

I have a project (with `main.cpp` and some headers. Yes, it is a Catch2 test project as described in this [blog](https://machinekoder.com/qt-unit-testing-catch-trompeloeil/)). It compiles and runs.

My problem is: This project does nothing useful unless I add some more source files (my test cases).
These source files use one header from the project and bring in some other dependencies as well (my library that I want to test).

The simple solution would be to copy this project, add the needed files and we are done.

Is there a better way? Currently with qmake I have the project defined in a `catch.pri` file. By including this in an project I have everything for the qt and catch2 setup, and only have to define the files with the testcases by modifying the `SOURCES`-Variable and the dependencies for the code to test.

Mapping this to **CMake** makes me ask questions:

First: when I include have a line like:

```
add_executable(tests main.cpp ${SOURCES})
```

Can I define `SOURCES` in a later line?

Second and more important: Is it a good idea to do it this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I define SOURCES in a later line?

Yes, but not the way you've done it. You can define your executable target `tests` with a few sources or **no** sources, but you can always append more sources later using the [`target_sources`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/target_sources.html) command.

```
add_executable(tests main.cpp)

...

# Later in the CMake file (or in another CMake file added via 'add_subdirectory').
target_sources(tests PRIVATE
    MyTestClass1.cpp
    MyTestClass2.cpp
    ...
)
```

You can similarly add compilation flags to this `tests` target later using [`target_compile_options`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/target_compile_options.html), and add dependencies to link to `tests` using `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: This way I could define my test target (the part of the test that is the same for all test projects) in a subdir; load it with `add_subdirectory` into my current test-project and add my test files, dependencies and furhter flags? This looks like the way to go for me.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy Yes, you can always append sources and additional compile flags/dependencies, even for a target defined in an earlier subdirectory of your CMake project.

Comment: But I can not `target_link_libraries` since I run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26838367/cmake-attempted-to-add-link-library-to-target-which-is-not-built-in-this-direct) problem.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy Yes, prior to CMake 3.13, you had to place the `target_link_libraries()` call in the same directory where the target was created. Upgrade your CMake to 3.13 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way?

No, this is how usually things are done. Any library / subproject is included using a `.pri` file. You can, of course, make the subproject a git-submodule.

> Can I define SOURCES in a later line?

Short answer: No

Example:

Lets say we have a small project with a single file `a.cpp` and a `CMakeLists.txt` as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(testing)
add_executable(testing ${sources})
#defining ${sources} later
set(sources a.cpp)
```

if you try to build this, it will result in an error:

> `No SOURCES given to target: testing`

I assume you want to separate the definition of `sources` variable to a separate file. In that case we can solve this as following. Assuming we have a dir structure as follows:

```
src/
|--lib/
|--tests/
|---- CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
main.cpp
```

Our cmake file will be same as before with these additional changes *before* `add_executable`:

```
add_subdirectory(tests)
```

In the `CMakeLists.txt` file inside `tests/` you can define the `${SOURCES}` variable:

```
set(SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.cpp
    PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

Note that you need `PARENT_SCOPE` here to make this `SOURCES` variable visible to the parent directory, which in our case is `src/`

Now in our main `CMakeLists.txt` we can use this variable:

```
add_executable(tests ${SOURCES})
```

> Second and more important: Is it a good idea to do it this way?

It depends. If you have a simple single directory project then it's not necessary. If you have multiple directories then of course, each directory should have its own `CMake` file which defines it's own variables. CMake files are code, they should be treated as code meaning they should be clean, modular and readable.

Comment: So in the `tests/CMakeLists.txt` I can place all modifications to the test project? Like adding dependencies to the `tests` executable. Or setting flags for the compilation?

Comment: You can add files only. But you can't add dependencies(external libraries) or flags because your target i.e., `tests` is in the main cmake file and is not defined yet. You can instead move the target to `tests/` directory and then set flags/add dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with defining the test_template as an static lib, which provides the main.cpp.

This way I define my tests as new executable, with test-files, library-dependencies and whatever, and only have to link to the static lib.